# Refresh or reload a datatable after using ajax call in mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**Here's my Html code:**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Extension File Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="ExtTableBody">
        @foreach (var item in Model.ExtSaved)
        {
            <tr>
               <td>@item.FileName</td>
                <td><a id="@item.Id" class="remove delete-user-row-with-ajax-button"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></td>
           </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("table").DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

**And There's the script:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("table").DataTable();
    });
</script>

<script>
    $("a.delete-user-row-with-ajax-button").bootstrap_confirm_delete({

        callback: function (e) {

           var button = e.data.originalObject;
           var Id = button.attr('id');
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "application/json",
                url: "/UploadFile/Remove",
                data: { Id: Id },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.UpdateDB == true) {
                        if (data.success > 0) {
                            button.closest('tr').remove();                                
                            $('#ExtSuccessText3').text("Extension File Removed Successufully.").removeClass("errormsg").addClass("successmsg");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

**My Action:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Remove(string Id)
        {
            int success = 1;
            ED.DELETEEXTENSIONBYID(Id);
            TempData["Message"] = "Extension successufully removed.";
            return Json(new { UpdateDB = true, success = success }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**When open the page**:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPdxU.png)

**after deleting a row:**

[The row will be deleted because of this line "button.closest('tr').remove();", but the datatable plugin didn't change "Showing 1 To 4 Of 4 Entries" to 3 of 3 entries, and when I choose from show entries to 25 or anything the row That I just deleted will be returned again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKGw5.png)

So I don't know what I have to do exactly.

Comment: <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("table").DataTable();
    });
</script>  
I just copied it twice here, I'm sorry.

Comment: are you trying to reload your dataTable?

Comment: dataTable = $("table").DataTable();   then dataTable.ajax.reload(null, false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove the row from the DataTable :

```
<script>
    var table //add an global variable
    $(document).ready(function () {
        table = $("table").DataTable();
    });
</script>

<script>
    $("a.delete-user-row-with-ajax-button").bootstrap_confirm_delete({

        callback: function (e) {

           var button = e.data.originalObject;
           var Id = button.attr('id');
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "application/json",
                url: "/UploadFile/Remove",
                data: { Id: Id },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.UpdateDB == true) {
                        if (data.success > 0) {
                            //remove the row from datatable
                            table.row( button.closest('tr') )
                                 .remove()
                                 .draw();                                
                            $('#ExtSuccessText3').text("Extension File Removed Successufully.").removeClass("errormsg").addClass("successmsg");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It worked well. Thanks Mostafa.
But I have another question, 
If I want to delete all rows, when I add on "Remove All" Button, what I should write?

Comment: I found the answer. :)
    $("table").DataTable().rows().remove().draw();

Comment: what if you want to add a new row of data ?

Answer (score 0):

try this example from Codeigniter

```
//add this at the top of your page
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

//assign a variable on your datatable 
var dataTable;
$(document).ready(function() {
    dataTable = $('#manufacturer_data').DataTable({  
       "ajax": "<?=base_url()?>manufacturer/manufacturer_list",  
    });     
});  

success: function(){
   //if your ajax call is success call the dataTable variable to make it reload
   dataTable.ajax.reload(null, false); 
}

//add this at the bottom of your page
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please add some more information so that other readers can more easily understand what this code does.